Eviction process in TN for 19 year old son who refuses to work/get a job or go to school/trade school
I would like to know the proper legal steps to evict my 19-year old son who refuses to work/get a job or go to school/trade school. Without going into all of the backstory, he has lived in our home off and on since he was almost 17. He has been in our home again full-time since February 2024. My husband (his biological father) has told our son if he challenges parental authority again, he will have to leave, but I am not sure we can just tell our son to hit the road unless he were to become violent. So far, he has not been physically violent, but he has been verbally abusive toward me, usually when his father isn't around.
I understand what tenancy-at-will is, but I would like to know how many days notice we are required by TN state law to give our son in written notice to evict. Also, can we use a template found on online for DIY document, or should we invest in a lawyer?
And if it helps, he has not paid any form of rent since around May or June 2024.
Thanks for any advice.

As the close notice says, this is a request for rather specific advice, which is beyond the scope of the site.  So in short you should probably consult a lawyer. They'll help you do the eviction properly, and can also advise you on things like how to document the abuse you allege and what legal consequences and options it may create.
